# How can I restrict the size of the LinkedTransferQueue?

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I am implementing the producer/consumer pattern and using LinkedTransferQueue collection.

I do not want my producer to exceed certain memory limitations.

Currently I am using this check, but from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedTransferQueue.html#size()), size operation require O(N) traversal. For my current implementation it is fine,

> but is there any better approach than the one, which I am currently
>   using ?

```
LinkedTransferQueue<String> producerStringLinkedTransferQueue = new LinkedTransferQueue<String>();

if (producerStringLinkedTransferQueue.size() <= 5000) {
    producerStringLinkedTransferQueue.add(<some data>);
}
```

Comment: This is certainly not the way to do it. ["determining the current number of elements ... may report inaccurate results if this collection is modified during traversal."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedTransferQueue.html)

Comment: agreed :), as I do not have to be very strict with size validation, i used this approach, but it should not be used , if the size validation is very strict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want do nothing when queue is full (not replace its oldest item as, for example, Apache commons collections `CircularFifoQueue` does), then you can wrap `LinkedTransferQueue` in your custom class and implement needed methods for calculating queue's size:

```
public class LimitLinkedTransferQueue<E> {
    LinkedTransferQueue<E> queue = new LinkedTransferQueue<>();
    private final long maxSize;
    private long size = 0;

    public LimitLinkedTransferQueue(long maxSize) {
        super();
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
    }

    public boolean add(E e) {
        if (this.size == this.maxSize){
            return false;
        }
        boolean result = queue.add(e);
        if (result) {
            size++;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public E take() throws InterruptedException {
        E item = queue.take();
        size--;
        return item;
    }
    // other need methods
}
```

Comment: Pretty good solution. It would be worth implementing some interfaces such as `Iterable`. You can (and should) make `maxSize` final by removing `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. It's also not thread safe - `LinkedTransferQueue` is a concurrent collection, so I would expected a limited one to be thread safe also.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've edited answer for `maxSize` and also it is need to improve code for thread safe.